# To underline menu item on reaching particular section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop a menu highlighting on scrolling the window. The respective menu item will be underlined when scroll is reached to the section. I am really finding it tough to obtain the same and struggling with this very badly. Being a novice in designing I am unable to achieve. Please share some insights on this, will be very helpful. Following is the menu items that I want to work on.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
    <li class="active"><a data-scroll href="#wmc" class='hidden-xs hidden-sm' >Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#agenda" class='hidden-xs hidden-sm'>Agenda</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#wmcpartners" class='hidden-xs hidden-sm'>Partners</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="https://www.aafmindia.co.in/EventRegistration.aspx" class='hidden-xs hidden-sm'>Register</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#contact" class='hidden-xs hidden-sm'>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle bottompad0 dropbtn hidden-xs hidden-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Past Events
 <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-content">
<li><a href="gallery2018.html">2018</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery2017.html">2017</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery2016.html">2016</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery2015.html">2015</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery2014.html">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery2013.html">2013</a></li>
</ul>
h</li></ul>
```

Comment: I used google and found this: https://codepen.io/clokey2k/pen/jgfFD

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am finding this really tough to implement. The existing classes are conflicting. The whole design is getting out of form .Completely not getting any way out.

Comment: Im right now at work so i cant help more (no time), but if nobody helps you till then i will come later to put a solution for you. Advice only for now = from my link i posted use only Javascript part.. and try to set it with your classes :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious time. I really appreciate. I have set the classes with the javascript on the link that you have provided. I wish I find you back soon.

Comment: You posted the HTML, but what have you tried to accomplish this? You tagged this with jQuery, yet posted none.

Comment: @EveryScreamer I could not find the solution over this. If you find some time,can you please show some insights on this. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution i wrote for you... use this.. this works.. you need to make some adjustments but this works.. I hope i helped :)

```js
$(window).scroll(function () { //on scroll event on window
        var position = $(this).scrollTop(); //position scrolled sofar
  
        $('.section').each(function() { //for each loop(chcecks for every element with that class)
        //for your every section on site or your class of main sections you are targetting
            var target = $(this).offset().top;//each element position from top
            var targetBot = target + $(this).height();

            var id = $(this).attr('id'); //this element ID - should be same as data-id on your nav link
            $('nav a[data-id=' + id + ']').removeClass('hovered'); //clearing
            if (position >= target && targetBot >= position) { //if you are scrolled over element with some id 
                $('nav a[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('hovered');
                //this will check wich element you are scrolled on and selects in menu that item with same data-id :) 
            }
        });

});
```

```css
section{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  color:white;
  font-size:70px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}


#mainSection{background:red;}
#nextSection{background:blue;}
#lastSection{background:gray;}

nav{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:400px;
}

nav a{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  text-align:left;
  background:white;
  padding:5px 15px;
}

nav a.hovered{
background:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<nav>
<a href="" data-id="mainSection">Main section</a>
<a href="" data-id="nextSection">Next section</a>
<a href="" data-id="lastSection">Last section</a>
</nav>

<section class="section" id="mainSection">
  Hello :)
</section>
<section class="section" id="nextSection">
  Hello :)
</section>
<section class="section" id="lastSection">
  Hello :)
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Do i need to write the classes again? because it will not be possible as the design may get disrupted.

Comment: I tried with this code. First, I used the styling and it made the whole page disrupted. This stopped me from moving ahead.

Comment: You were lifesaver. Thanks a tonn !! It worked so well. Thank you once again for your effort. Keep doing good work. World needs more people like you .